# How to open side menu not open by button click?

Tags: ios, ecslidingviewcontroller

I am using ECsliding controller for slide menu.swipe gestrure working good in my case but when click button nothing happened.

My case is:

After two screen, I wanted to show slide menu so i have set ECSlide like belowe in my second screen and so far everything ok.
In third view controller I set a button to show menu.Button get clicked but menu not open.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    if (![self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController isKindOfClass:[LeftViewController class]]) {
        self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController  = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LeftViewController"];
    }

   [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    if ([self.checkStr isEqualToString:@"1"])
    {
        //provider
        UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                                                 bundle: nil];

        LeftViewController *leftMenu = (LeftViewController*)[mainStoryboard
                                                             instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"LeftViewController"];
        // Create your menu view controller
        ProfileController *leftMenuONE = (ProfileController*)[mainStoryboard
                                                                      instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"ProfileControllerID"];






        // configure top view controller
        UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:leftMenuONE];

        self.slidingViewController = [ECSlidingViewController slidingWithTopViewController:navigationController];
        self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController  = leftMenu;

        // enable swiping on the top view
        [navigationController.view addGestureRecognizer:self.slidingViewController.panGesture];

        // configure anchored layout
        self.slidingViewController.anchorLeftRevealAmount = 250.0;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.slidingViewController animated:YES];

    }
    else
    {
        //user
        UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                                                 bundle: nil];

        LeftViewController *leftMenu = (LeftViewController*)[mainStoryboard
                                                             instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"LeftViewController"];
        // Create your menu view controller
        UserProfileController *leftMenuONE = (UserProfileController*)[mainStoryboard
                                                                      instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"UserProfileControllerID"];






        // configure top view controller
        UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:leftMenuONE];

        self.slidingViewController = [ECSlidingViewController slidingWithTopViewController:navigationController];
        self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController  = leftMenu;

        // enable swiping on the top view
        [navigationController.view addGestureRecognizer:self.slidingViewController.panGesture];

        // configure anchored layout
        self.slidingViewController.anchorLeftRevealAmount = 250.0;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.slidingViewController animated:YES];

    }
}
```

LeftViewController is my menu view controller.

Third view controller will load based condition.example if string is one,it will go to one view controller otherwise anther view controller.

Thirdview.h

```
- (IBAction)menuAction:(id)sender
{


        [self.slidingViewController anchorTopViewToRightAnimated:YES];

}
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (![self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController isKindOfClass:[LeftViewController class]]) {
        self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController  = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LeftViewController"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir you need to look in gesture method called and what code there for slide Menu view Controller. and do same code at your button click event.

Comment: https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController/issues/271 have u checked this

Comment: @NitinGohel actually gesture working by default there is i didnt put anycode..

Comment: check default code and understand it how in example working.

Comment: @Sport i tried that but not worked.what i want to know here,did i set sliding correctly or not?if it is correct then should work.why button action working?

Comment: @NitinGohel i cant find any code for that from their class file

Comment: check in storyBoard there is direct defined method gesture.

Comment: i dont know...everthing i worked with programmatically..i dont understand here